# How to add users to atlassian jira using database tables?

Tags: jira

I need to create bunch of users using JIRA database.
I already have imported my list into JIRA database and I have tried to insert them into cwd_user table but these users are not visible in JIRA application.

I'm using JIRA 5.2.11 and database is mysql

Answer (score 0):

For all database-level changes*, you *must* restart JIRA. Otherwise it's DAO layer won't see your changes.

I hope, you were aware of the group memberships, users has to be added into, to enable them to log in.

*Except watchers and `jiraissue`.